# Socket.io JS Client returning connection false

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Im trying to connect the socket in my client js file but the response im getting is always false and no socket.on function is working

```
<script>
    debugger
    const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

    console.log('check 1', socket.connected);
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('check 2', socket.connected);
    });

    socket.on("connect_error", (reason) => {
        console.log('check 2', reason);
        socket.connect();
 });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('check 2', socket.connected);
    });
</script>
```

No function is running but looking at the network debugger it is returning 200 response . Any help would be apprecaited

Comment: recheck the docs, `io.connect` is not right

Comment: still not working with just `io(http://example.com)`

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Nothing in this code appears to be incorrect, so the problem is likely elsewhere (say, your server, for example, or how you're running it/ports you're using).